# Equivalent of Monitor Wait/Pulse in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have been programming professionally in the .NET world for a while using C# and now I have a need to utilize Python in a concurrent/multi-threaded environment. One of the constructs I am most familiar with is the object Monitor Wait/Pulse for synchronizing my asynchronous operations.

Is there any such similar construct in Python?